# Firebase-database: Structure for event application with data consistency

Tags: json, firebase-realtime-database

As many have before me, I am building an event app using Firebase as the database.

After watching this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1n9Kw3AORw I think that my current data structure is wrong so I want to change it.

This is something that I hope will keep track of which events users have been to, their responses, check ins and help update user information like in the video.

```
{
    "events": {
        "event1": {
            "title": "Event 1",
            "venue": {
                "venue1": true
            },
            "guests": {
                "user1": true,
                "user2": true
            }
        },
        "event2": {}
    },
    "locationHistory": {
        "location1": {
            "user1": true,
            "user2": true
        },
        "location2": {
            "user3": true
        }
    },
    "userCheckIns": {
        "event1": {
            "user1": true
        }
    },
    "userResponses": { // not sure about these responses
        "event1": {
            "user1": true,
            "user2": false,
            "user3": "maybe"
        },
        "event2": {}
    },
    "eventGuests": {
        "event1": {
            "user1": {
                "name": "user name 1"
            },
            "user2": {
                "name": "user name 2"
            }
        },
        "event2": {}
    },
    "userEvents": {
        "user1": {
            "event1": true
        },
        "user2": {
            "event1": true
        }
    },
    "venues": {
        "venue1": {
            "name": "Venue name",
            "location": "location1"
        },
        "users": {
            "user1": {
                "name": "user name 1",
                "events": {
                    "event1": true
                }
            },
            "user2": {
                "name": "user name 2",
                "events": {
                    "event1": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no singular correct data structure for NoSQL databases such as Firebase. The best structure depends solely on the use-cases of your app. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s). After that post back if you have a specific use-case that you're having a hard time modeling.

Comment: I will. Thank you.